# Where should Exceptions be put that are used by multiple projects?

Tags: java, exception

I need to refactor a project with two data models into two separate projects.
Both projects use the same Exceptions.
Should I create a 3rd project only for these exceptions? Cloning sounds like a no-go.

Comment: I would keep them in a separate jar and combine the jar with the two projects after build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you should create it on a separate project, and use it as a dependency on the others. It is not uncommon to see a project/jar that only has the exceptions used in the modules that you work with. It's a fine way to keep things organized IMHO.

Comment: Not agreed, having only exceptions in common between two projects sounds smelly to me. I believe they are just the same in their class names and nothing more!

Comment: I believe OP means 2 modules in the same project, not actually 2 independent projects. If that is the case this solution as well as this question makes no sense. Even package names would be strange.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO,as @harsha mentioned in existing comment ,the easiest solution would be to put the shared code into a  **library or .jar file**  and the .jar file to your project library.

Now you have an valuable api which can be maintained  easily for each build with your versions.

Answer (score 1):

A separate project that is a shared dependency of the other two is probably best. Duplicating the objects would make things difficult if the two data models are used together, which you would have to resolve via e.g. different package names, and which would create maintenance headaches. The shared project may be a good repository for future shared code beyond just your exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Are there just exceptions in common? It sounds weird.

Are there any dependency between these projects? Is one is other's client?

I believe there shall be some interfaces in common too, some which declare these exceptions in their methods' signature. Some which are implemented in one of your projects, and get called in other project.

If there are no such thing at all, it seems your common exceptions are just in common by their names! They are not really the same classes, they just have the same name, and because many of the user-defined exceptions are just having constructors which call `super` constructors, they seem to be the same.

If that's your case, I would not bother myself to extract the classes, and I would keep the duplications, because there is nothing gained by the refactoring.

Comment: They are two models for two (actually more) different systems that are used to import data into a target system. There are more things in common that I already put in an util project. But I don't think exceptions should go there, as one system might not need the utils but the exceptions.